# IE8/9 - Submitting form with image file async - no formData support

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, form-data

I'm trying to build a form to asynchronously upload images to my site. It works perfectly on newer browsers and then the AJAX updates my list of images without refreshing the entire page.

The problem I'm having is it doesn't work on IE8 & IE9 (and probably others) because those browsers don't support "FormData". I need an alternative where a user uploads an image (with additional hidden form input fields), the list of images should update after the upload is complete - WITHOUT having the entire page refresh.

Here is basically what I have so far:

```
<div class="imagelist">
... list of images here should be updated by ajax after each upload...
</div>

<form name="uploadform" id="uploadform" method="post" action="/edit-images/uploadimage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="itemimagesid" value="<?php echo $itemid; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="itemtype" value="new" />
  <input type="file" name="imagefile" id="imagefile" onchange="uploadFile()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadFile() {
  if (!window.FormData || window.FormData === undefined) { // old crappy browsers that can't use ajax/file submit.
    $('#uploadform').append("<input type='hidden' name='oldbrowser' value='1'>"); 
    ...
    [ need a solution here ]
    ...
    return;
  }
}
</script>
```

I need something that works in 2016. I have bootstrap 3.3.2 which uses the jQuery version 1.11.2. I've searched stackoverflow and none of the solutions work. I've tried "jQuery Form Plugin", that does absolutely nothing, doesn't even initialize - probably because my jQuery version is too new for that script. Hopefully there is a better solution for today.

Comment: The solution is, use async if you can, and if the browser doesn't support formData, then just trigger a form submit :)

Comment: The old iframe upload hack still works perfectly fine in IE8, so you could do that. There's probably an old tutorial around somewhere, noone really supports IE8 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was able to figure out the iframe hack.